# spring junit test data preparrer class access repositories trough field

Tags: spring, kotlin, testing, junit

I have simple class annotated with @Component and injected repositories like

```
@Component
class TestsDataPreparer(
    private val carRepository: CarRepository
) {

fun withCar(builder: Car.() -> Unit = {}): Car {
    return carRepository.save(
        Car(
            name = builder.name!!
        )
    )
}

}
```

which is clear..

But i wonder if it would be ok to do something like this, or if it is considered as anti-pattern.

```
@Component
class TestsDataPreparer(
    val carRepository: CarRepository
) {

fun withCar(builder: Car.() -> Unit = {}): Car {
    return carRepository.save(
        Car(
            name = builder.name!!
        )
    )
}

}
```

```
@Test
fun testCar() {
   testsDataPreparer.withCar{this.name="Super-cool-car!"}
   assertThat(testsDataPreparer.carRepository.findAll()).hasSize(1)
}
```

So the question is if it is okay to not inject repository in test class itself, but reuse it from TestsDataPreparer class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, making an originally private field public just for testing [can be considered an antipattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126545/would-you-rather-make-private-stuff-internal-public-for-tests-or-use-some-kind). Instead, you can create a `CarRepository` instance and then pass it to `TestsDataPreparer` when you create it. But for unit testing, you don't actually need that, you can use a mock and verify that the correct method was called (`CarRepository.save`).